# html5-reset theme does not show the image

Tags: theme-development, themes

I am started to create a custome theme based on the `HTML5-reset` theme that a downloaded from GitHub. before touching/modifying anything, just I tried to put an image under the `get_header();` and above the loop, using the following HTML code snipet:

```
<div class="the-image">
    <img src="images/moonrise_100.jpg" alt="moonrise" />
</div>
```

but when I tried to see the result, unexpectedly showed nothing but the icon of broken-images, so inspected the element for any error or overriding using chrome but I can't find anything incorrect.
What can be the origin of this.
i checked everything, directory, name, image suffix and ...
I use: xampp server.

Comment: You will need to add full path of the image. `<img src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/images/moonrise_100.jpg" alt="moonrise" />`

Comment: @Roberthue you mean that there is no why to use relative addresses even by using wordpress functions?

Comment: It depends on where you want to place your image. Relative image URL might work for a particular image/case but might not work uniformly all over website, specially when pretty permalinks are enabled. So to be safer, you should use full URLs. Any special reason why you want to use relative path for images?

Comment: If you want to use relative paths in the themes files that have the header.php you can set the html base -> http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_base.asp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Code is not readable in comment so I am adding it here. With a little explanation.

You will need to add full path of the image file to show them in theme. If your image is in theme directory then you will have to use theme directory path variable `bloginfo('stylesheet_directory')` with image name. So this is the code you will need to add in your theme files.

```
<div class="the-image">
    <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/moonrise_100.jpg" alt="moonrise" />
</div>
```

Comment: I would say `get_template_directory_uri()` is more explicit choice and better for parent/only theme (or link will break when child theme is added).

Comment: Yes, didn't think of that. :P corrected. Thanks @Rarst